# Unique fixed points of $h\circ g$ and $g\circ h$

Tags: metric-spaces

$g : X → X$ and $h : X → X$ be
contractions on X, and let $y, z$ be the unique fixed points of $g \circ h$ and $h \circ g$ respectively. Show that $h(y) = z$ and $g(z) = y$

My attempt is that, since $g$ is contraction, then there exists a unique point such that $g(x)=x$ similarly for $h$, not sure how to connect the informations.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $g$ and $h$?  Also, what are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: The assumption on h,g that they are contraction, which I should have written in the question 

Comment: I tried thinking of writing things down, but I don't know how to proceed any hint will be appreciated

Comment: @rasheda564 At least update the question with the appropriate hypothesis on the maps... and start to write what you can using definitions until you’re stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $h(g(h(y))) = h(y)$, so $h(y)$ is a fixed point of $h \circ g$, hence equals $z$. And vice versa.